# .NET Active Directory authorization in 2 tier application

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, windows-security

Let's say we have a PC station (windows 10) joined to Active Directory and there is a user that signed in.

I have an application (client layer connects straight ahead to database). Currently, The application prompts for login / password upon start, however I want to change that and if the current user is connected to domain (sign in the system), give him access right away without prompting for credentials.

I can imagine that once user is logged to system, the account can be in the meantime disabled, or password needs to be changed or password expired. Since I don't have password for the account, the question is

How Can I validate currently logged user in Active Directory to gauge whether I can give him access to the application or not?

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Comment: @FalcoAlexander Look at my answer. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

you can check [windowsidentity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.getcurrent?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1):

```
bool System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().IsAuthenticated;
string System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().IsAuthenticated.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

And here is my solution. It reaches AD directory and checks if account is really there and verifies its enabled for authentication property. Maybe somebody will help that.

```
public class ADAuthentication 
{
    private string userPrincipalName = UserPrincipal.Current.UserPrincipalName;
    private string userName = Environment.UserName;

    public string UserPrincipalName
    {
        get { return userPrincipalName; }
        set { userPrincipalName = value; }
    }

    public string Username
    {
        get { return userName; }
        set { userName = value; }
    }

    private string domainName;
    private string container;

    public enum AuthenticationMode { Credentials, ActiveDirectory };

    public AuthenticationMode GetAuthenticationType()
    {            
        if (String.Equals(domainName, Environment.UserDomainName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            try
            {
                using (var domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName, container))
                {
                    using (var foundUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainContext, IdentityType.UserPrincipalName, userPrincipalName))
                    {                            
                        if (foundUser != null && foundUser.Enabled == true)
                            return AuthenticationMode.ActiveDirectory;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (AuthenticationException)
            {
                return AuthenticationMode.Credentials;
            }
            catch (PrincipalServerDownException)
            {
                return AuthenticationMode.Credentials;
            }
        }
        return AuthenticationMode.Credentials;
    }

    public ADAuthentication (string domainName)
    {            
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(domainName))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The domainName parameter is required.");

        string[] parts = domainName.Split('.');
        this.domainName = parts[0];
        this.container = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
        {
            string separator = string.IsNullOrEmpty(container) ? "" : ",";
            this.container += string.Format("{0}DC={1}", separator, parts[i]);
        }
    }                
}
```